# Convert HTML to PDF using DroidText library & android

Tags: android, html, pdf

I want to convert a html file to PDF
https://github.com/bullda/DroidText

I used this tutorial
http://karanbalkar.com/2013/05/tutorial-22-generate-pdf-using-droidtext-in-android/

And I can generate simple paragraphs.

I've looked over this library and found that there are some tools for HTML parsing

[image]

But I can't figure out how to do this.

Comment: Did you figure out if it's capable of converting HTML to PDF ? The documentation is really poor.

Comment: I didn't figure it out.

Comment: Waiting on this too.